# Value-copy whole worksheet to another one with PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, copy

There are some posts already about how to copy-move one WS or copy some ranges, but what I am interested in is how to copy whole WS as a values into already existing WS in an other workbook. This is what I tried:

```
$obj_excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$obj_excel.DisplayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user
# Open source and target files
$wb_source = $obj_excel.Workbooks.Open($SourceFile, $null, $true) # open source, readonly
$wb_target = $obj_excel.Workbooks.Open($TargetFile) # open target
[void]$wb_target.Sheets.Item($TargetSheet).Copy()
[void]$wb_source.Sheets.Item($SourceSheet).PasteSpecial(-4163)
$wb_source.Close($false) # close source workbook w/o saving
$wb_target.Close($true) # close and save destination workbook
$obj_excel.Quit()
```

and it's apparently not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to copy the content you can't use the [`Copy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-copy-method-excel) method of the `Worksheet` object. Use the [`Copy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copy-method-excel) method of the `Range` object (specifically the `Cells` collection):

```
$wb_source.Sheets.Item($SourceSheet).Cells.Copy()
$wb_target.Sheets.Item($TargetSheet).Cells.PasteSpecial(-4163)
```