# Split excel sheets without cell formula (links) using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have excel with multiple sheets and I'm trying to split sheets into separate workbooks. Excel sheets are linked between, so when I split them cells will have linked values. Do you have idea how to split excel sheets but paste only values, without formulas?

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application" 
$Excel.Visible = $false  
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false  

$filepath ="C:\Users\XX\Documents\2020\XXX_test.xlsx"
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.open($filepath)
$WorkbookName = "test.xlsx"
$output_type = "xlsx"

if ($Workbook.Worksheets.Count -gt 0) { 
    write-Output "Now processing: $WorkbookName" 
    $FileFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlOpenXMLWorkbook 

    $WorkbookName = $filepath -replace ".xlsx", "" 

    foreach($Worksheet in $Workbook.Worksheets) {
        $Worksheet.Copy()
        $ExtractedFileName = $WorkbookName + "~~" + $Worksheet.Name + "." + $output_type 
        $Excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs($ExtractedFileName, $FileFormat) 
        $Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

        write-Output "Created file: $ExtractedFileName"
    }
} 

$Workbook.Close() 
$Excel.Quit() 
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
Stop-Process -Name EXCEL
Remove-Variable Excel
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47860293/9898643) help you? (thevalue used in the `PasteSpecial()` method is from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype)

Answer (score 0):

The [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.1.0) module makes this easier.

```
Import-Module ImportExcel
$filepath ="C:\Users\XX\Documents\2020\XXX_test.xlsx"
$output_type = "xlsx"
$sheets = Get-ExcelSheetInfo -Path $filepath
foreach ($sheet in $sheets) {
    $ExtractedFileName = "{0}~~{1}.{2}" -f ($filepath -replace '\.xlsx$'),$sheet.Name,$output_type
    Import-Excel -Path $sheet.Path -WorkSheetName $sheet.Name |
        Export-Excel -Path $ExtractedFileName
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not my private laptop so I do not have administrator rights to instal this module. Thank you for your answer. Maybe there is another way to extract only values without formulas?